# How To Extract Attributes from a html5 tag string

Tags: javascript

i have a string:

`<input type="text" data-id="1" />`

and i want to allow the user to extract attributes from this html5 input tag string.

like this

`from('<input type="text" data-id="1" />').extract("type")`

i have tried this:

```
function from(str) {
    return {
        extract: function (attr) {
            return str.split(attr)
        }
    }
}
```

but this does not work.

how can i achieve this?

by using only javascript.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you think `split` would work?

Comment: Also, _why_ are you doing this? Why not use the DOM directly instead?

Comment: split() is a good starting point, but you will have to do more. Check what split gives you and how it works.

Comment: I deleted my answer that initially suggested `DocumentFragment` and then `<template>`, because @nitrin0's answer using `DOMParser` is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you going:

```
let x = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<input type="text" data-id="1" />', "text/xml");
x.firstChild.getAttribute("type"); // text
```

Comment: ooooh, TIL about `DOMParser`! Thank you